# How to identify (or connect) User id with incoming socket?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, client

I need to identify the unique id of Socket. That's the right way to use socket descriptor?
Is socket descriptor unique?

> For example

```
QTcpSocket* pClientSocket = nextPendingConnection();
int id = pClientSocket->socketDescriptor();
User user(id);

/*...*/

void slotReadClient(){
socket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
user = users.find(socket->socketDescriptor());
user->doAny();
}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something here, are you looking for a locally (ie. within the process) unique identifier? the socket descriptors are only valid so long as the socket is not closed

Comment: When new connection occurs i have to save some uniq thing in object. Look at sample. In new connection slot i create an object user and connecti signals and slots. In sloReadClient i want to change something in user object. For example (abstract code) QString name = read(socket); user->setName(name); But how to identify socket ?  I have got an array of users and have to change needful object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket ids (which are actually file descriptors) are instantaneously unique over their lifetime. Meaning the following:

```
int my_fd socket(...);

/* during this time no calls to socket will ever return my_fd */

close(my_fd);
```

I'm not sure the specifics of what you mean by user id, I think that this wouldn't work because if the same user connects twice they will have different fds (probably). However if you simply want a way to identify the present connections and don't carry about id persistance across sessions then this is exactly how it should be done.